# ActiveRecord query for each user's latest email address in a table of email addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I wanted to keep track of user's changing their email addresses so I created a "users" table which is referenced by an "emails" table.  The contents of the "users" table is unimportant for this question.  The "emails" table contains a string "email" column as well as the usual "id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at" columns.  When a user's email is changed, a new record is added to the "emails" table which references the user by "user_id".  So any given user could have multiple email addresses in the "emails" table, but only the latest one is relevant contact information.

The models are setup as follows:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :emails
end

class Email < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to get a listing of all users' current email addresses.  I'm looking for a way to do this with maybe one or two queries, not iterating through every user.  I'm guessing it's something like the following:

```
Email.order(created_at: :desc).group(:user_id)
```

but that seems to give me the oldest email address for every user, not the latest.  I'm currently using Rails 5.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but...

```
sql = "SELECT *
FROM emails e1 WHERE (user_id,id) IN 
( SELECT user_id, MAX(id)
  FROM emails e2
  GROUP BY user_id
)"

Email.find_by_sql(sql)
```

If you really need to use `created_at` to determine the ordering, then, so long as `created_at` values are unique, you can replace `id` above with `created_at` and get the same results.

However, if at all possible, I strongly suggest you add an is_primary flag to the table to allow a user to clearly denote the email address that they expect to be contacted with.  You would also want to add logic and validations to ensure only one email per user_id had is_primary = true.

This change would also eliminate the need for the nested grouped query you were forced to discover herein.

Comment: I'm loath to say it, but you might be right about adding an "is_primary" flag.  Your solution works in mysql, but it doesn't work in sqlite, which I'm using for initial testing.  The "is_primary" flag might be the most compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several ways to do it, you can try this one:

```rb
Email.all.group(:user_id).order("max(emails.created_at) DESC")
```

Comment: This is still giving me the oldest record in a group, not the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
emails=Email.all.group(:user_id)
Ordered_emails = emails.sort_by &:created_at
```

Comment: This gives me the oldest email for each user.  I need the newest email for each user.

Comment: then add this line at the end "

emails = Ordered_emails.reverse! "